# Alter every table of a schema that has a name like 'something'?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'd like to know if it is possible to alter every single table in a schema that contains a column name like 'something' in Oracle DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible. You have to dynamically create the DDL or DML and `execute immediate` out of a `PL/SQL` routine. With "alter" do you mean change the content of the tables columns or do you mean change the columns properties?

EDIT:

You can use Frank's Routine but for a column modify you do this.

```
l_SQL := 'alter table ' || cur.table_name || 
         ' modify (' || cur.column_name || ' varchar2(50)); ';
```

I agree with Frank to not blindly modify the columns, use the dbms output as a generated script.

EDIT2:

There is one more thing I realized. Table `user_tab_columns` gives you also columns of views. You could exclude them by joining with `user_tables`:

```
set serveroutput on
declare
  l_SQL varchar2(4000);
begin
  for cur in (
    select utc.table_name, utc.column_name 
     from user_tab_columns utc
     join user_tables      ut  on  (UT.TABLE_NAME = utc.table_name)
    where upper(utc.column_name) like '%SO')
  loop
    l_SQL := 'alter table ' || cur.table_name || ' modify (' || cur.column_name || ' varchar2(50)); ';
    dbms_output.put_line(l_SQL);
    -- execute immediate l_SQL; -- UNCOMMENT TO RUN; DO NOT DO THIS IN PRODUCTION!
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: I need to set those column at the same string length

Comment: See my EDIT to modify columns

Comment: Thanks a lot @hol!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a loop to iterate over `USER_TAB_COLUMNS` and generate the SQL statement:

```
declare
  l_SQL varchar2(4000);
begin
  for cur in (
    select table_name, column_name 
     from user_tab_columns utc
    where upper(utc.column_name) like '%SOMETHING%')
  loop
    l_SQL := 'alter table ' || cur.table_name || ' drop column ' || cur.column_name;
    dbms_output.put_line(l_SQL);
    -- execute immediate l_SQL; -- UNCOMMENT TO RUN; DO NOT DO THIS IN PRODUCTION!
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Frank